# How to show HTTP response status of rest API in serenity report through feature file

Tags: cucumber-java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I want to show the http status code and response  in serenity report. I am using the cucumber plus java and serenity framework.
Please find below my code.

Feature file 
Feature: Get Google address

Scenario: Predit google Address 
Given API is set up

Then  I get the Http status code and response

**Step definition file**:

```
@Given("^API is set up$")
public void setUp() {

}

@Then("^I get the Http status code and response$")
```

Serenity BDD Report

Given API is set up 
SUCCESS

Then I get the status code and response 
SUCCESS

Answer (score 0):

You can define global variable in your framework and use it as you can see in the [custom reporting Tutorial of Serenity](https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/extended-reports.html).

```
report.customfields.user = ${API_RESPONSE_CODE}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity Runner:

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(...)
```

then you can use this helper method:

```
import net.thucydides.core.steps.ExecutedStepDescription;
import net.thucydides.core.steps.StepEventBus;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public static void showMessage(final String message) {
    String escapedMessage = message;
    escapedMessage = StringUtils.replace(escapedMessage, "|", "&#124;");
    escapedMessage = StringUtils.replace(escapedMessage, " ", "&nbsp;");
    escapedMessage = StringUtils.replace(escapedMessage, "_", "&#95;");
    StepEventBus.getEventBus().stepStarted(ExecutedStepDescription.withTitle(escapedMessage));
    StepEventBus.getEventBus().stepFinished();
}
```

This will print any message on the Serenity-Report of the current Step-Execution

---

For your special case you can use [serenity-rest-assured](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-rest-assured)

```
    SerenityRest.given()
            .contentType("application/json")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .body("{...}")
            .when().post("/...")
            .getStatusCode();
```

It generates a button into the serenity report where all details of the Requests are shown.
See the last Screenshot on the Article:
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/restful-api-testing-using-serenity-and-rest-assured-a-guide/